# Print_r(response) in Java version

Tags: java, response

I have this code in Java that connects to an API and retrieves some data. The connection is a success but I do not know how to print the response like PHP's `print_r` and see the response in JSON.

Java Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, UnirestException {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://sample.talentlms.com/api/v1/users/")
        .get()
        .addHeader("authorization", "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==")
        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        .addHeader("postman-token", "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")
        .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();          

    System.out.print(response);
}
```

Output:

`Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://sample.talentlms.com/api/v1/users/}`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who uses OkHTTP for HTTP requests. Just do the following in the printing.

`System.out.print(response.body().string());`